# Correct use of GNU Global tag files in different Git branches

Tags: git

I'm working on a large C++ project using many different Git branches. We're using the Git Flow model. This means I regularly switch between Git branches. I use helm-gtags in Emacs to navigate the code. At the moment I have not placed the GNU Global tag files (GTAGS, GRTAGS, GPATH) under Git version control, they simply stay put whenever I change to work on a different branch. But this might mean I have symbols in the tag files that are not present in the code, and vice versa. I can update the tag files (helm-gtags-update-tags) but this does not remove symbols from the tag files that are not present in the code, it only adds or update the symbols that are actually in the code.

What is the best way to work with GNU Global tag files in code that is version controlled by Git? Should the tag files be added to Git so that they are specific for each branch? Or should I perhaps delete the tag files every time I switch branch to generate a fresh set of tags? Or is there another way?

Comment: I agree, go ahead and migrate.

Comment: Put `global -u` in .git/hooks/post-checkout.

Comment: @politza does `global -u` deal with the problem of "does not remove symbols from the tag files that are not present in the code, it only adds or update the symbols that are actually in the code" ? I can only imagine that `helm-gtags-update-tags` is calling `global -u`, so it seems like it might be insufficient. If that's all that's needed, though, and it's smart enough to notice all changed files, then I would agree that this is clearly the simplest solution.

Comment: Looking at that function: You need a prefix arg to invoke `global -u`.

Answer (score 1):

Committing them doesn't seem like the best idea, and depending on how long it takes for global to reindex your entire project, you may find it undesirable to rebuild the whole database every time you change branches.

If a complete rebuild takes too long, here's the `post-checkout` git hook I wrote to manage untracked files on a per-branch basis.

For each branch you would simply copy your GTAGS, GRTAGS, GPATH files into an appropriately-named sub-directory of the `.branches` directory used by this script, and then the script will swap the files around whenever you change branches.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Git hook (post-checkout) to manage *untracked* files on a per-branch basis.
# Author: Phil S.
# Version 1.1
# URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42686433

## Commentary:
#
# This hook is very useful when you have development-specific files which
# you never want to commit to the repository, but which can vary on a
# branch-by-branch basis. Branch-specific configuration files are a
# prime use-case (to specify the database to use, for instance).
#
# With this hook, those files are automatically copied into the working
# copy when you checkout the branch they are associated with, and moved
# back again when you checkout another branch.
#
# The hook uses a .branches directory in the root of the repository,
# so you should add this to your .gitignore file.
#
# To start managing files for a branch, simply copy them into a sub-
# directory (of .branches) named after the branch in question, changing
# any forward slashes in the branch name into double-underscores.


## Example:
#
# [phil/master] ~/site$ grep .branches .gitignore
# .branches
#
# [phil/master] ~/site$ find .branches/
# .branches/
# .branches/phil__master
# .branches/phil__master/sites
# .branches/phil__master/sites/default
# .branches/phil__master/sites/default/settings.branch.php
# .branches/phil__media
# .branches/phil__media/sites
# .branches/phil__media/sites/default
# .branches/phil__media/sites/default/settings.branch.php
#
# [phil/master] ~/site$ git checkout phil/media
# Switched to branch 'phil/media'
# Removing untracked per-branch files for: phil__master
# `../.././sites/default/settings.branch.php' -> `./sites/default/settings.branch.php'
# Adding untracked per-branch files for: phil__media
# >f+++++++++ sites/default/settings.branch.php


## Caveat:
#
# An early version of this script had issues whenever a git operation checked
# out a detached HEAD, such that the .branches/.current_branch file contained
# "HEAD" rather than the branch directory name, and so the intended untracked
# files were not copied.
#
# I never got caught out by this, because my prompt always shows me the
# .current_branch value (see comments at the end of the hook), so I notice
# when it says HEAD unexpectedly; however I do not recall this happening at
# all in the past few years, so I believe it is no longer a concern.
#
# If it were to happen to you, simply running git checkout (branch) for the
# branch you are already on fixes it up. The log file may also help to debug
# any such issues.
#
# n.b. It's feasible that git could update the HEAD ref without performing
# a checkout (after initially checking out a detached head), but the cases
# I've observed (and fixed) were associated with rebasing, where this script
# had (undesirably) permitted its own processing to occur after an initial
# checkout of a detached HEAD, and had then exited early (as intended when
# rebasing) after the subsequent checkout of the eventual branch. The solution
# was to improve the detection of the cases in which we wish to exit early,
# to cover the former case as well as the latter.


## Changelog:
#
# v1.1: Handle additional text following "rebase" in GIT_REFLOG_ACTION.
#       Renamed $git_dir to $root (it's the working copy root, not .git)
#       Log git environment vars even when aborting.


## General information on Git post-checkout hooks:
#
# This hook is invoked when a git checkout is run after having updated
# the worktree. The hook is given three parameters: the ref of the
# previous HEAD, the ref of the new HEAD (which may or may not have
# changed), and a flag indicating whether the checkout was a branch
# checkout (changing branches, flag=1) or a file checkout (retrieving
# a file from the index, flag=0). This hook cannot affect the outcome
# of git checkout.
#
# It is also run after git clone, unless the --no-checkout (-n) option
# is used. The first parameter given to the hook is the null-ref, the
# second the ref of the new HEAD and the flag is always 1.
#
# This hook can be used to perform repository validity checks,
# auto-display differences from the previous HEAD if different, or set
# working dir metadata properties.

##############################################################################

head_old=$1
head_new=$2
flag=$3

# n.b. pwd will be this working copy's root directory.
root=$(pwd)

# Debug log.
log=".branches/post-checkout.log"
echo "\n$(date)" >>${log} 2>&1
if test -f .branches/.current_branch; then
    echo ".current_branch: $(cat .branches/.current_branch)" >>${log} 2>&1
else
    echo ".current_branch (file missing)" >>${log} 2>&1
fi
echo "Old: $(git log --max-count=1 --decorate ${head_old} | head -1)" >>${log} 2>&1
echo "New: $(git log --max-count=1 --decorate ${head_new} | head -1)" >>${log} 2>&1

# Log the GIT environment variables. This is primarily to assist with finding
# workarounds for any edge cases that might crop up. (This is how I discovered
# GIT_REFLOG_ACTION.)
set | grep GIT >>${log} 2>&1

# Check the 'flag' parameter ($3).
if test "$flag" != "1"; then # not a branch switch.
    echo "$0 aborted (not a branch switch)." 2>&1 | tee -a ${log}
    echo "Check ${log} for details."
    exit 0
fi

# This hook is also invoked with flag=1 when rebasing, which we never want.
# We only want to move the untracked files around when we have explictly
# requested a checkout (which also means that the .current_branch file must
# only ever be updated at those same times).
if test "${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION##rebase}" != "${GIT_REFLOG_ACTION}"; then
    echo "$0 aborted (GIT_REFLOG_ACTION indicated rebase)." 2>&1 | tee -a ${log}
    echo "Check ${log} for details."
    exit 0
elif test -d "$root/.git/rebase-merge"; then
    echo "$0 aborted (.git/rebase-merge indicated rebase)." 2>&1 | tee -a ${log}
    echo "Check ${log} for details."
    exit 0
fi

# Determine which .branches directory we were originally using.
# There is no pre-checkout hook, but we can include a marker file amongst
# the untracked files identifying the current branch name, and use that to
# update the versions of the files under .branches from the current versions
# before copying the new versions.
cd "$root"
if test -f .branches/.current_branch; then
    oldbranch=$(cat .branches/.current_branch)
    oldbranch_dir=".branches/$oldbranch"
    if test -d "$oldbranch_dir"; then
        echo "Removing untracked per-branch files for: $oldbranch"
        cd "$oldbranch_dir"
        find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0r -I{} mv -v -f ../../{} {}
    fi
fi

# Establish the name of the newly checked-out branch.
cd "$root"
newbranch=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
newbranch=${newbranch##refs/heads/}
newbranch=${newbranch:-HEAD}
newbranch=$(echo $newbranch | sed 's/\//__/')
newbranch_dir=".branches/$newbranch"

# Create/update marker file.
test -d .branches || mkdir .branches
echo $newbranch >.branches/.current_branch
echo ".current_branch: $(cat .branches/.current_branch)" >>${log} 2>&1

# Copy across the untracked files needed for the new branch.
echo "Adding untracked per-branch files for: $newbranch"

if ! test -d "$newbranch_dir"; then
   echo "$newbranch_dir not found; nothing to update."
   exit 0
fi

cd "$newbranch_dir"
rsync -r -i . ../../

# You can also set a fancy prompt in bash to show you which branch you're in.
# (Used to be super-useful when rebasing was a problem, but probably still
# handy just for confirming that things are as they should be.)
# PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@ [\$(cat /var/www/(site)/.branches/.current_branch | sed 's/__/\//')] \w\$ "

# Local Variables:
# outline-regexp: "^##"
# eval: (outline-minor-mode 1)
# eval: (while (re-search-forward "^## .+:" nil t) (outline-toggle-children))
# End:
```

Personally I've never made the switch from Ctags to Global, and I use a rather brute-force approach to the general problem of keeping my TAGS file up to date, which is to use a timer to run an asynchronous shell command to establish whether any file has been modified more recently than TAGS and, if so, build a new TAGS file. If the new file is different to the old file I replace the old one and set Emacs' tags completion table to nil so that it will re-read the TAGS file next time.

Rebuilding the TAGS file is therefore my solution both to making code changes in the current branch as well as to switching to another branch, so I've never had much of a reason to use my post-checkout hook for the purpose I've suggested here. Depending on when the timer fires, there can be a few minutes delay between code changes and the TAGS file catching up, though, so a more immediate response would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tag files are associated with a specific version of the code, I believe you should check them in.

On the other hand, they're files specific to one style of working with the code, and so not generally applicable to the project, and so it can be argued that it shouldn't be checked in. They'll be constantly changing and adding a lot of noise to each commit. Noise that everyone else has to look at.

What I'd suggest instead is to look into configuring emacs so it automatically updates its view of the files automatically when they change. This is what most modern editors do. [Here's a technique using inotify](https://blog.chmouel.com/2009/07/03/update-emacsvim-tags-with-inotify/). Or, and I know this is heresy, it might be time for a new editor. I switched from emacs to [Atom](https://atom.io/) this year.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the end. I started out adding the tag files to git. But this proved to not work well with branching and merging and in the end the tag files would not contain all the symbols in the current branch and nothing more anyway. phils answer led me to check up on git hooks. I removed the tag files from git versioning and created a post-checkout hook that silently deleted all tag files present when changing branches. When helm-gtags in Emacs detects that there are no tag files it offers to generate them. For my project which is rather large it doesn't take long. helm-gtags also detects when a file has changed and automatically updates the tag files with only these changes. So now I have a system that automatically keeps tag files up to date with all symbols in the current branch. So far it is working well.